# Simple collection mapping with MyBatis and Kotlin fails with "argument type mismatch"

Tags: kotlin, mybatis

I am trying out MyBatis with a Kotlin app, but I fail to make a simple collection mapping work.

For testing, I trimmed down my code to

```
data class Role(
    var id: String
)

data class AppUser @AutomapConstructor constructor(
    var id: Int,
    var name: String,
    var email: String,
    var roles: MutableList<Role>
)

interface Mapper {
    fun selectAllUsers(): List<AppUser>
    fun selectAllRoles(): List<Role>
}
```

and this in my mapper xml

```
    <resultMap id="userResultMap" type="de.eekboom.kotlin_mybatis.AppUser">
        <id property="id" column="id" />
        <collection property="roles" javaType="ArrayList" ofType="de.eekboom.kotlin_mybatis.Role">
            <id property="id" column="role_id"/>
        </collection>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="selectAllUsers" resultMap="userResultMap">
        select u.*, uxr.role_id
        from app_user u
        left join app_user_x_role uxr on u.id = uxr.app_user_id
    </select>

    <select id="selectAllRoles" resultType="de.eekboom.kotlin_mybatis.Role">
        select * from role
    </select>
```

`selectAllRoles()?` works fine, but `selectAllUsers()` fails with

```
Error instantiating class de.eekboom.kotlin_mybatis.AppUser with invalid
types (int,String,String,List) or values (1,Foo Bar,foo@bar.de,ADMIN).
Cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

I studied the MyBatis "Result Maps" docs and also tried a lot of variations (like leaving out the explicit `javaType` or trying different list types in the Kotlin data class).

Simple, self-contained example is here: https://github.com/eekboom/kotlin-mybatis

### Rationale

Kotlin favours unmutable types and especially declaring properties that are not meant to be null as non-nullable types.
It also offers data classes that save a lot of code (by automatically giving equals, hashCode and toString implementations), so I'd like to

- use a **data class**
- use **unmutable** properties
- use **non-null** properties, so that I don't have to "cast" them to not-null later
- use constructor injection (so that the properties can really be unmutable and so that I could add initialization code that gets executed after all properties are set

Comment: A constructor that takes collection cannot be used by MyBatis. It is technically difficult (see the [discussion](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/101) if you are interested). You may need to 1) define a constructor that does not include `roles` and 2) use `<constructor>` in the result map (see the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#constructor)).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, to summarize:

To use a collection in conjunction with constructor mapping is hard to implement, the mybatis maintainers are unsure if its valuable enough and in any case it is just not currently possible .

It's strange however, that [the docs for constructor](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#constructor) mapping in mybatis say this (emphasis mine):

> resultMap
>
> This is the ID of a ResultMap that can map the nested results of this argument into an appropriate object graph. ... It allows you to join multiple tables together into a single ResultSet. Such a ResultSet will contain **duplicated, repeating groups of data** that needs to be decomposed and mapped properly to a nested object graph. ...

### Alternatives

Give up and use a mutable (non "data") class with nullable properties:
Works, but

- does not use constructor, no place for initialization code
- needs mutable properties
- needs nullable properties - another app layer must cast to not-null types
- needs manual implementation of equals, hashcode and toString here - about 20 extra lines of code

```
class AppUser {
    var id: Int? = null
    var name: String? = null
    var email: String? = null
    var roles: List<Role>? = null
}
```

I found that this also works and has not-null and unmutable property declarations, but

- needs an extra "dummy" constructor just for mybatis
- mybatis still mutates the properties after construction
- the collection is declared as unmutable, but actually backed by a mutable collection
- still has no place for initialization code (an `init {}` block would run too early)

```
data class AppUser (
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val email: String,
    val roles: List<Role>
) {
    private constructor(): this(0, "", "", mutableListOf())
}
```